# Get RFID Scanner input jQuery

Tags: jquery, rfid

I am using an RFID scanner with my web application, and I'd like for the page to be listening for the scanner input in the background.

The scanner reads the 10 digit RFID tag and transmits it as standard keyboard input.
The number that the page recieves will always be 10 digits, and will always be transmitted very quickly, much faster than anyone can type.

Is there any way to catch the 10 digits with jQuery, and then have the string of numbers to process with the database?

Thanks for your help.

Also, as far as I can tell, the scanner does not send any special headers before the code, unless there is a program that can tell me this, I don't see the jQuery Barcode Listener plugin as being an option. http://code.google.com/p/jquery-barcodelistener/

But it does automatically press enter after the code is scanned.

I do know that I could just use a text input, but the scanner will be used for employees to track their hours, and the employee should not be able to see the number that is being entered into the page, because this should prevent tampering, and just typing in someone elses number to clock them in or out.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the problem.

You're saying the scanner sends the content (of the scan) as key strokes.

You want to catch it? Then just make sure a text `input` element, in the page, has the focus.

Next, you could get it like that:
`var input = $("#text_box").text();`

I'm sorry if I missed your point.

**Edit #1:**

> I do know that I could just use a text input, but the scanner will be
>   used for employees to track their hours, and the employee should not
>   be able to see the number that is being entered into the page, because
>   this should prevent tampering, and just typing in someone elses number
>   to clock them in or out.

Ok now that's your "problem".

It's very simple: You could do one of the following:

1) Hide the text input, just look for "how to hide element". Also, to make sure this element has focus you need to, with jQuery, use `$("text_box").focus()`.

2) Catch the key press/click event of the page and record these.

I'd go for #1.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect the application of the scanner.

Comment: your idea is partially ok, i have same question. However, it' snot sufficient. At the same time i want: to track only inputs that fulfill certain criteria: 1. Catch only 10 digits in less than a second, no meter what else client is doing on webpage, when key stroke happens, js gets value and process it. Those criteria makes it really useful for web application. Other than that is experimenting.